# Servlet Throws Exception at Runtime in Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, servlets

Whenever I run my servlet in eclipse it shows:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I already connect the jar file properly and set the path in build path config. Is there anything else I can do?

Uninstall and re-install MySQL?

```
{
    [...]
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection
        ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example","root","root");
    String qr="select * from details where name=? and pwd=?";
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(qr);
    ps.setString(1, name);
    ps.setString(2, pwd);

    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next())
    {
        out.println("home");
    }
    else
    {
        out.println("Invalid name and password");
    }
    con.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    out.println(e);
}
```

I expect the output "home" or "invalid name and password"

Comment: The JAR file with JDBC driver must be either in `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your application, or in Tomcat's `lib` folder. So put the JDBC driver JAR file to the `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the web-application Eclipse project, and (re)deploy your web application.

Answer (score 1):

> Uninstall and re-install MySQL?

No.  The problem is in your Java client code, not the MySQL installation.

You should no longer do this:

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

The correct way is to just call:

```
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

with the correct JDBC url, username and password.

This is the correct way to use `DriverManager` for any JDBC 4.0+ compliant driver; see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html).  The `DriverManager` class initialization will use the service provider mechanism to find and load the actual driver class.

The most likely reason your code doesn't work is that the fully qualified classname of the `Driver` class has changed in Connector/J 8.0.   Basically, your code is asking the JVM to load a class that no longer exists.

If this doesn't explain / fix your problem (i.e. you are using Connector/J 5.1 or earlier), then the most likely explanation is that the you don't have the driver JAR file on the above code's *runtime* classpath.  But the code change is advisable anyway.